# Is there a Delphi implementation of Google Data APIs?

Tags: delphi, google-data-api, atom-feed

Google offers [various libraries](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/clientlibs.html) for interfacing with the Google Data APIs.  Currently these do not include Delphi (Win32) support.

Has anyone done any work on a Delphi interface to Google Data, or the underlying Atom/AtomPub protocols?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=209&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary&start=100) with Google suggesting that they create one.

> Thanks for your suggestion.
>
> This probably isn't likely to happen anytime in the near future, as we need to
>   concentrate our available resources in other areas.
>
> However, GData is based upon standard XML and HTTP requests, so work on a Delphi
>   client library can certainly be done outside Google.  I'll leave this issue open so
>   others can vote for it, and perhaps someone in the community can pick this up.

So you can [vote it up](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=209&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary&start=100).

Answer (score -1):

You can choose one of I have googled

- https://webdelphi.ru/2013/05/testirovanie-zaprosov-k-api-google-sredstvami-delphi-komponent-oauthclient-dlya-delphi-xe-xe3/
- https://ngucrit.blogspot.com/2018/01/delphi-xe-rest-client-library.html

or google some others.